# Aurelia: Multiple Slots in Template?

Tags: html, aurelia, aurelia-templating

Is it possible to have multiple slots in a custom component?

i.e.

```
<template>
   <slot id="first"></slot> 
   <slot id="second"></slot>
</template>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but you should use `name` instead of `id`.

```
<template>  
  <div>
    The first slot:
    <div>
      <slot name="slot1"></slot>
    </div>
    The second slot:
    <div>
      <slot name="slot2"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

It's documented here for now: http://blog.durandal.io/2016/05/23/aurelia-shadow-dom-v1-slots-prerelease/ I'll be adding this to the content projection section of the Custom Elements documentation soon.

Comment: btw do all projection tags(slot, router-view, content) allow the fallback content?

Comment: This is only for slot. Note that content is going away